# Unable to access the elements in iframe in Puppeteer

Tags: selenium, iframe, frameworks, puppeteer

```
 await page.isElementVisible('iframe');
    console.log('iframe is ready. Loading iframe content');
    const elementHandle = await page.waitForSelector("iframe[id='payment-form']");
    const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
```

its working till this point

```
    // console.log('filling form in iframe');       
    
    const cardType = await frame.$x(`//div[contains(@class, 'css-12kbcej')]//select[@data-elid="card-type"]`);
    await page.click();
```

also try to do this one as well

```
 await page.waitForXPathAndClick(`//div[contains(@class, 'css-12kbcej')]//select[@data-elid="card-type"]`);
```

and this as well

```
    const cardType = await frame.$x(`//div[contains(@class, 'css-12kbcej')]//select[@data-elid="card-type"]`);
    await frame.click(cardType);
```

But nothing works out

**Error Message**

> Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': The provided selector is empty.
> at **puppeteer_evaluation_script**:1:33

Answer (score 0):

You have `await page.click();` -- `page.click()` requires a selector, eg `page.click('myCssSelector')`. That's why you're getting that error, `The provided selector is empty`

Comment: this is what I get when I pass a selector to the page.click()
 const cardType = await frame.$x(`//div[contains(@class, 'css-12kbcej')]//select[@data-elid="card-type"]`);
        await page.click(`//div[contains(@class, 'css-12kbcej')]//select[@data-elid="card-type"]`);
        
`     Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '//div[contains(@class, 'css-12kbcej')]//select[@data-elid="card-type"]' is not a valid selector.`

Comment: The xpath is invalid, maybe because your are mixing single and double quotes? try `//div[contains(@class, "css-12kbcej")]//select[@data-elid="card-type"]`

Comment: `const elements = await page.$x('//div[contains(@class, "css-12kbcej")]//select[@data-elid="card-type"]')
        await elements[0].click() `

Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: I think its not able to access the elements in the iframe. :(

Comment: Then you should identify and switch to the iframe, using `driver.switch_to_frame(iframe_element)`

Comment: Okay let me try